# How to get phone number from contact?

Tags: java, arrays, string

I have two `String[]`, one with names and the other one with phone number. If I select one name from list, how can I call phone number of that person from Dialog box. For example, first person in first `string[]` has a phone number of `second[]`. How to get that number?

```
package com.mkyong.android;

import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.ListActivity;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemClickListener;

public class ListFruitActivity extends ListActivity {

    static final String[] Imena = new String[] { "Aleksandar Panic", "Dubravka Protic", "Milutin Panic",
            "Jelica Panic", "Nemanja Gagic", "Doris Dragojevic", "Milica Protic", "Kiki Beba",
            "Dule Savic", "Miroslav Miskovic", "Petar Djuric", "Dragoslav Joksimovic", "Petar Petrovic" };
    static final String[] Brojevi=new String[] { "0638638045", "062450050", "065045324", "05443",
            "06535475", "564218", "546567", "514574","5454333","444787","413133","354867","24879"};

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.list_fruit,
                Imena));

        ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setTextFilterEnabled(true);

        listView.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {


                AlertDialog.Builder adb=new AlertDialog.Builder(ListFruitActivity.this);
                adb.setTitle("Odabir");
                adb.setMessage("Izabrali ste profesora "+parent.getItemAtPosition(position));


                adb.setPositiveButton("Call",new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                    public void onClick (DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                    Intent i=new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_DIAL,
                        Uri.parse("tel:+651234567")); //here is the problem, how to get the right number
                    startActivity(i);
                    }
                });
                adb.show(); 
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Comment: Pretty sure this is java so I added that tag to get you better answers.

Comment: Why are you using two `String[]` arrays instead of a class called `Contact` that has the properties `name` and `number`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why do you need two `String[]` arrays?

You have two options to implement it in a better way:

1. Use a `Map<String, String>` to store name as key and phone number as value.
2. Create a class `Contact` to store all your contact details like name, address, phone number, email etc and then use a `List<Contact>` or an array (recommended way of doing this).

Comment: Maybe I don't understand very well, I want to make some kind of predefined address book, that will be only readable... Please help :)

Comment: You can first create a class which has various properties like name, phone number etc. Later, in your ListFruitActivity you can create an unmodifiable set or list populated with predefined contacts so that it is read-only - http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/collections/implementations/wrapper.html

Comment: I found the solution, simply instead on number in Uri.parse i putted "tel:+"+Brojevi[position].toString()) Thank you for the effort.

Comment: While that works, it is error prone. If you don't add names and phone numbers in the same order, then your name-phone number mapping will be wrong. The relationship between Imena and Brojevi is not clear which makes it difficult to maintain later.